# How to configure a health check by HTTP URL on Apache Tomcat Load Balancer?

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing

I'm running an Apache Tomcat Load Balancer and 4 Apache Tomcat Instances. I want to check the health of the instances by HTTP URL on the load balancer.

How to configure a health check by HTTP request (URL/URI) on Apache Tomcat Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to achieve this :
1. Ideally, you should provide a url that is served by your application. This way if the application goes down, then the load balancer stops sending requests to it. Make sure that the url you provide is very lightweight. Ideally, a very simple html page that displays something as simple as "success"
2. If the above is not an option, then --either-- provide a url that already exists, say `/sample/index.html`, `/manager/index.html`  --or-- just deploy a simple application that displays a  lighweight html page.